# How can I get value from application.yaml in test environment

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, yaml

I need to get a value from my application.yaml in production environment like this:

```
@Value("${user-service.defaultAdminId}")
    private final String DEFAULT_ADMIN_ID;
```

This value will be set up in userProfile variable in RegistrationService class:

```
private UserProfile notClientMapper(UserRegistrationForNotClientDto userRegistrationForNotClientDto) {
        PassportData passportData = passportDataMapper.toEntityDataFromRegistrationForNotClientDto(
                userRegistrationForNotClientDto);
        Client client = clientMapper.mapTo(
                userRegistrationForNotClientDto, passportData);
        UserProfile userProfile = userProfileMapper.toUserProfileFromRegistrationForNotClientDto(
                userRegistrationForNotClientDto, client);

        userProfile.setAdminId(UUID.fromString(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ID));
        userProfile.setQrData(qrDataGenerator.generateQRData());
        passwordEncoder(userRegistrationForNotClientDto.getPassword(), userProfile);
        return userProfile;
    }
```

Well, my issue is when the application run in production environment everything work, but I also need to pass unit test for this block of code like this:

```
@Test
    @DisplayName("When correct dto for registration not client then return after success registration for not client dto")
    public void returnAfterSuccessRegistrationForNotClient() {
        UserRegistrationForNotClientDto newUserNotClientDto
                = DtoCreatorForTest.getUserRegistrationForNotClientDto();
        mockTuneUpsCreateAfterSuccessRegistrationDtoForNotClient(newUserNotClientDto);

        UserAfterSuccessRegistrationForNotClientDto expected =
                DtoCreatorForTest.getAfterRegistrationNotClientDto(newUserNotClientDto);
        UserAfterSuccessRegistrationForNotClientDto actual =
                registrationService.registrationForNotClient(newUserNotClientDto);
        Mockito.verify(userProfileRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(any());
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

And in test environment a DEFAULT_ADMIN_ID related to the value in applicatin.yaml is't set up.
So, not surprisingly I get a NPE.
I'm confused what can I do to fix this problem.

I try to get the value from application.yaml in test environment.
Expecting to get that one.
Actually getting NPE.

Comment: It looks like a unit test since you use mocks? In that case, you don't want to access the application.yaml at all. You should probably create a constructor setting the value instead of using field injection, so you can create the object in your test with a fixed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the configuration properties version:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="user-service")
@Data
class UserServiceProperties {
 private String defaultAdminId;
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor 
class RegistrationService {
 private final UserServiceProperties properties;
 
 private UserProfile notClientMapper(UserRegistrationForNotClientDto userRegistrationForNotClientDto) {
  ...
   userProfile.setAdminId(UUID.fromString(properties.getDefaultAdminId()));
  ...
 }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RegistrationServiceTest {
 private final static String defaultId = "some-valid-uuid";

 @Mock
 private UserServiceProperties properties;

 @InjectMocks
 private RegistrationService registrationService;

 @BeforeEach
 void setup() {
  when(properties.getDefaultAdminId()).thenReturn(defaultId);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value in the constructor instead of attaching the annotation to the field.

```
@Service
class RegistrationService {
 private final UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;
 private final String defaultAdminId;

 public RegistrationService(UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository,
                            @Value("${user-service.defaultAdminId}") String defaultAdminId) {
  this.userProfileRepository = userProfileRepository;
  this.defaultAdminId = defaultAdminId;
 }
}
```

Then you can choose the admin Id in your test freely without having to access the actual value from the application.yaml.

```
class RegistrationServiceTest {
 private final static String defaultId = "some-valid-uuid";

 private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

 private RegistrationService registrationService;

 @BeforeEach
 void setup() {
  userProfileRepository = mock(UserProfileRepository.class); // or use @Mock etc
  registrationService = new RegistrationService(userProfileRepository, defaultId);
 }
}
```

Comment: I am using Lombok and @RequiredArgsContructor. Is there a way to use your way in my situation?

Comment: @UladzislauNiamira We also prefer to use Lombok; these are the cases we make an exception. Spring `@ConfigurationProperties` are an alternative, but I guess for a single String that's overkill.